# Dollar sign jquery as string : unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I manipulated some html to display a little form in a modal bootstrap like this :

```
$.each(response, function(i, item){
    detail += "<div><input name='detail-tipe' type='checkbox' value='" + response[i].nama_detail + "' class='detail-tipe' /> " + response[i].nama_detail.toString() + "</div>";
});

detail +=  "$('.detail-tipe').each(function(){
    var attrib = $(this).attr('value');
    for ( var j=0, k = remo.length; j < k; j++ ) {
        if(attrib == remo[j]){
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        };
    }
})";
```

But, dollar sign is unterminated. Is it possible
Please, advise.

Comment: Why are you concatenating `detail += '$('.detail-tipe')....`? Clearly you understand it's a script

Comment: Try to put your code into < script > < / script >

Comment: is it possible I post the script  as string

Comment: The issue is your multi-line strings need a \ character at the end of each line (well that's one issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a multi-line string to a variable, you need to put a `\` at the end of each line to tell the interpreter that the string is continuing. Otherwise it thinks you want to start a new line of actual code.

```
detail += "$('.detail-tipe').each(function(){ \
  var attrib = $(this).attr('value'); \
  for ( var j=0, k = remo.length; j < k; j++ ) { \
    if(attrib == remo[j]){ \
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked'); \
    }; \
  } \
})";
```